# JSON file select key and values got error

Tags: python, json

my json file looks like this :

```
{'id_str': '1179123803420598275',
 'quote_count': 0,
 'lang': 'hi',
 'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 'geo': None,
 'user': {'id_str': '832041700394749952',
  'verified': False,
  'id': 832041700394749952,
  'translator_type': 'none',
  'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6',
  'contributors_enabled': False,
  'url': None,
  'location': 'karnavati City, India',
  'name': 'Hemraj Padhiyar',
  'profile_background_image_url_https': '',
  'protected': False,
  'screen_name': 'hemrajpadhiyar',
  'profile_use_background_image': True,
  'profile_text_color': '333333',
  'default_profile_image': False,
  'following': None,
  'listed_count': 3,
 ......

 'timestamp_ms': '1569959996453',
 'favorited': False,
 'is_quote_status': False,
 'coordinates': None,
 'contributors': None,
 'place': {'place_type': 'city',
  'attributes': {},
  'bounding_box': {'coordinates': [[[72.436739, 22.923256],
     [72.436739, 23.104662],
     [72.703725, 23.104662],
     [72.703725, 22.923256]]],
   'type': 'Polygon'},
  'full_name': 'Ahmadabad City, India',
  'country': 'India',
  'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/272983f6b52c196e.json',
  'country_code': 'IN',
  'id': '272983f6b52c196e',
  'name': 'Ahmadabad City'}}
```

I want to select the values of certain keys, e.g. 'text', 'location' within the 'user' key, and 'coordinates' within 'bounding_box' within 'place'.

several selections are successful, but when I want to select the 'coordinates' within 'bounding_box' within 'place', it gives me error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Here's my code:
The following 4 lines all worked:

```
all_id_str = [one_read['id_str'] for one_read in json_read]
all_text = [one_read['text'] for one_read in json_read]
all_coord = [one_read['coordinates'] for one_read in json_read]
all_location = [one_read['user']['location'] for one_read in json_read]
```

But the following 2 lines relating to 'place' don't work:

```
all_country= [one_read['place']['country'] for one_read in json_read]
all_bbox = [one_read['place']['bounding_box'] for one_read in json_read]
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
----> 1 all_country= [one_read['place']['country'] for one_read in json_read]
      2 all_bbox = [one_read['place']['bounding_box'] for one_read in json_read]
```

in (.0)

```
----> 1 all_country= [one_read['place']['country'] for one_read in json_read]
      2 all_bbox = [one_read['place']['bounding_box'] for one_read in json_read]
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I've tested whether any single dictionary contains none /null value for key "place", but they all return empty []

```
[one_read for one_read in json_read if one_read['place'] == 'None']
[one_read for one_read in json_read if one_read['place'] == 'Null']
```

output:
[]

Anyone can help?

Comment: The `place` dictionary has no `country` key.. Use `one_read['country']` instead

Comment: These work for me, which makes me think that some of the json's you have other than the posted one may have missing data. I would use try except block to skip those

Comment: agree. But I runed two test to test whether the value of place have 'None' and 'Null' , they all return empty, which means there's no None or Null.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions to deal with or test the missing value?

Answer (score 0):

`one_read['place']` is not valid.

You should be doing `one_read['user']['place']['country']` to grab the country

Comment: But the key "place" is not within user, place is an independent key, I checked the .key(), and output is:  dict_keys(['id_str', 'quote_count', 'lang', 'extended_tweet', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'geo', 'user', 'possibly_sensitive', 'retweet_count', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'reply_count', 'created_at', 'display_text_range', 'text', 'retweeted', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'entities', 'id', 'source', 'favorite_count', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'filter_level', 'truncated', 'timestamp_ms', 'favorited', 'is_quote_status', 'coordinates', 'contributors', 'place'])

Comment: Besides, when I just choose one line of dictionary (one id) to select the place key, it worked, just not work when you want to loop it over.

Comment: In the JSON you provided, `place` is 100% inside the `user` key, and is nowhere outside the `user` key. Please provide the entire JSON if you want more help. It seems like you provided some truncated JSON which makes this almost impossible to debug